# Can I have a trailing dot at the end of a number?

Tags: arithmetic

Is  `12.` a valid way to say `12.0`

I was trying it with python. If I say `a = 12.`, python will treat `a` as `12.0`. So I was wondering if it is a valid way to represent a floating point number?

Comment: If you want it to be, sure. Mathematics doesn't really have any official documentation like Python does.

Comment: Regret is right, but this notation is certainly nonstandard within mathematics, so if you use this notation in a mathematical context (say, as opposed to a Python-specific one) it will help your reader if you include a note describing the notation.

Comment: That's one way to represent it, but I like the following:
$$
12=\frac{8\pi\sqrt{2}}{3267}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(4k)!(1103+26390k)}{(k!)^4396^{4k}}.
$$
Or is that just me?

Comment: Ok I realise the question is not that brilliant. Thanks guys!

Comment: @crash I am sure it is just you. :P

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow, that's just you. I can't memorize that. I can remember $2^4 - 2^2$.